# access plotly behind proxy

Tags: r, proxy, plotly

I'm trying to make an interactive version of my ggplot2 using the plotly package. It works fine when I do it from a personal computer. 
Unfortunately, I'm at work, on a windows machine behind a proxy, and it fails to connect to the plotly server. Browsing the code source, I think the issue might be with the `postFrom` function from `RCurl`. I [tried adding the proxy](https://github.com/baptiste/plotly/commit/9a185d717215e54f6842c4e9f3de9c9d01e70f58#diff-eb044f253f9369d7d0711127e6035fbbR86) to `options(RCurlOptions = list(proxy="http://proxyurl:8080"))`, but that doesn't seem to improve things. Is there a known workaround?

```
library(httr)
set_config(use_proxy(url="http://proxy.xxx.fr",port=8080,username="",password=""))
options('RCurlOptions'= c(options('RCurlOptions'), list(proxy = 'http://proxy.xxxx.fr:8080')))
library(plotly)
set_credentials_file(username="baptiste", api_key="xxxx")

require(plotly)

p2 <- qplot(1,1)
py <- plotly(username="baptiste")
out <- py$ggplotly(p2)
# Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : couldn't connect to host
```

Answer (score 5):

`pub$makecall` in plotly.R overwrites your global RCurlOptions. I've submitted a pull request to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

I think that if you set your RCurl options like this:

```
opts <- list(
  proxy         = "myweb.proxy.com", 
  proxyusername = "myproxyuser", 
  proxypassword = "myproxypassword", 
  proxyport     = 8080
)

options(RCurlOptions = opts)
```

Then you should be able to connect to the host, at least this works for me behind my work proxy.

Comment: I can't actually test this anymore, since I don't work at this workplace anymore. The other answer suggests that there was a fix on the plotly side.